# Get directory of website on the filesystem using PHP

Tags: php, url, document-root

I have a website in my local computer. I am using wamp server to run my website.

URL for website is **http://localhost/mywebsite/**

I put a PHP file in my website inside folder **mywebsite/component/add/files/add.php**

So the actual path of file is `c:\\wamp\www\mywebsite\component\add\files\add.php`.

I want to show path **c:\wamp\www\mywebsite** in my file.

How can I get it? And in future when I move my site to somewhere else, I don't need to change path manually. It must be update automatically. Is there any function for this?

e.g. If I move my site in **mywebsite/demo**, the path will be **C:\wamp\www\mywebsite\demo**

I hope this is clear to understand. I don't want to show **http://localhost/mywebsite** path there.

Can anyone help me ???

Comment: In your situation, I would create a variable that is accessible on every page (via an include) that contains a prefix and then prefix this to your urls, i.e. `$Prefix = './mywebsite';` and then `<a href="<?php echo $Prefix; ?>/demo">View our demo</a>`. When you move your site, you would simply change the `$Prefix` to something like `./newwebsite'`, all of your links would automatically update.

Answer (score 2):

[The $_SERVER array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) should have the information you're looking for.  For example:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

This would be the configured document root for the PHP server.  In your case, I believe that would be `c:\wamp\www`.  You can also use:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
```

This would be the absolute path of the current running script.  There are also some [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) that contain useful information, particularly if you also have PHP scripts running outside of a web server context.  (Background tasks, etc.)

Comment: Wouldn't this show c:\wamp\www instead, as mywebsite is a sub-folder of www, which is the main application folder?

Comment: @Gavin: Good point, I didn't catch that.  Answer updated.  Looks like Rinzler had the right idea, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

or

```
 Perhaps you want: dirname(__FILE__)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
```

or alternatively

```
str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', dirname(__FILE__));
str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', __DIR__); // works only in php > 5.3
```